# error instanceof X doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a class called `UserInputError` that extends `Error`

```
export default class UserInputError extends Error {
    constructor(message: string) {
        super(message);
        this.name = "UserInputError";
    }
}
```

When i try to catch this specific error i use

```
try {
     // some code
} catch(e: any) {
    // catch logic here
    console.log(e instanceof UserInputError, e.name === "UserInputError");
```

The output is

```
false true
```

why `instanceof` doesn't work as expected? does context matter? or was it because I've used `any`?

Edit:

This is the code snippet that throws the error

```
if (invalidNumberOfMethods) {
    throw new UserInputError("you must chose one method");
}
```

**NOTE1:** I don't `throw UserInputError` instead of `throw new UserInputError`

```sh
> grep -R --include "*.ts" --exclude-dir=node_modules "throw UserInputError" .
> echo $?
> 1
```

**NOTE2:** I'm using this with NodeJs, not the browser.

Comment: Maybe you are throwing the class itself (`throw UserInputError`) instead of an instance of it (`throw new UserInputError()`)? `UserInputError.name` will also be `'UserInputError'`... Or maybe you are importing the error incorrectly and `UserInputError` in the second file isn't what you think it is? Please show a **minimal, reproducible example**, including the part that throws the error and the part that imports the class.

Comment: You may want to include your tsconfig.json since you're using TypeScript. When things get transpiled from TypeScript to JavaScript (especially when going to ES5), things get a little dicey. Throw webpack or something like that in the mix, and there's more room for things to go wrong.

Comment: @HereticMonkey when changing it to ES6 it worked as expected

Comment: Makes sense; ES6 has classes so those wouldn't need to be transpiled, and `instanceof` would work.